# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.1' (T_DNUMBER) in C:\webserver\function\GrabStatus.php on line 7

Tags: php, syntax-error

I'm getting the error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.1' (T_DNUMBER) in C:\webserver\function\GrabStatus.php on line 7
```

in my websites php minecraft server ping script

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php
$settings = parse_ini_file('../db.ini',true);

$ipandport = explode(':',$settings['mcserver']['ip']);
if(empty($ipandport[1]))
{
$ipandport[1] = 192.168.1.33:27747;
}

// Edit this ->
define( 'MQ_SERVER_ADDR', $ipandport[0]);
define( 'MQ_SERVER_PORT', $ipandport[1]);
define( 'MQ_TIMEOUT', 1 );
// Edit this <-

// Display everything in browser, because some people can't look in logs for errors
Error_Reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
Ini_Set( 'display_errors', true );

require __DIR__ . '/MinecraftServerPing.php';

$Timer = MicroTime( true );

$Info = false;
$Query = null;

try
{
    $Query = new MinecraftPing( MQ_SERVER_ADDR, MQ_SERVER_PORT, MQ_TIMEOUT );

    $Info = $Query->Query( );

    if( $Info === false )
    {
        /*
         * If this server is older than 1.7, we can try querying it again using older protocol
         * This function returns data in a different format, you will have to manually map
         * things yourself if you want to match 1.7's output
         *
         * If you know for sure that this server is using an older version,
         * you then can directly call QueryOldPre17 and avoid Query() and then reconnection part
         */

        $Query->Close( );
        $Query->Connect( );

        $Info = $Query->QueryOldPre17( );
    }
}
catch( MinecraftPingException $e )
{
    $Exception = $e;
}

if( $Query !== null )
{
    $Query->Close( );
}

$Timer = Number_Format( MicroTime( true ) - $Timer, 4, '.', '' );



if(isset($Info['players']))
{

echo $Info['description'].'<Br>';
echo 'Players: '.$Info['players']['online'].' / '.$Info['players']['max'].'<br>';
echo 'Ping: '.$Timer;
echo '<br><br>';

}
else
{
echo 'Server is offline.';
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

192.168.1.33:27747  is  not valid number

you should write like this

```
$ipandport[1] = '192.168.1.33:27747';
```